# Git Post-Receive Hook is Inconsistently Adding Changes

Tags: php, git, branch, githooks, git-post-receive

I am trying to write a post-receive hook which will pull in all new branches pushed to a bitbucket account. Then, if the person who pushed those changes is a designated user of a particular development site, the branch should automatically be checked out.

This is the code:

```
$payload = stripslashes(($_POST['payload']) ? $_POST['payload'] : $_GET['payload']);
$obj = json_decode($payload);

$commits = $obj->commits;
$head_commit = $commits[0];

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($commits); $i++) {
    $commit = $commits[$i];
    $head_date = strtotime($head_commit->timestamp);
    $comm_date = strtotime($commit->timestamp);

    if ($comm_date > $head_date) {
        $head_commit = $commit;
    }
}

$branch = $head_commit->branch;
$author = $head_commit->raw_author;

$msgs = array();                                
$ini = parse_ini_file('pull_settings.ini',true);
define ("CURRENT_SITE",$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);

foreach ($ini as $server) {
    if (CURRENT_SITE==$server["site_name"]) {
        if ($server["type"]=="master") {
            $users = $server["users"];
            if (in_array($author,$users) && $branch == "master") {
                exec("git pull",$msgs);
            } else $users = array();
        }
        if ($server["type"]=="dev") {
            exec("git stash",$msgs);
            exec("git fetch --all",$msgs);
            $users = $server["users"];
            if (in_array($author,$users)) {
                exec("git checkout -f $branch",$msgs);
                exec("git merge origin/$branch",$msgs);
            } else $users = array();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this:

It doesn't always work! Sometimes it won't checkout the branch even if it should. Also, sometimes it leaves files behind when it checks out new branches. This results in git saying a whole bunch of files were modified that weren't within the branch it is in.

Please Help! Very stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

git stash will save modifications done of tracked files. If you have new files, they won't be saved. Can't this be possibly one of your problem ? You have new untracked files which will be then added by your git merge.

Comment: new files wouldn't halt the merge though i don't think? the process is literally stopping mid way through the script

Comment: New files can be a problem if they are untracked on the local repo, and you try to merge a remote repo adding tracked files with the same name.
It would stop the merge at the begging.